# Submatches in vim substitute branches

Tags: regex, vim

I want to search using a number of branches, and take the submatch from the matching branch to use in the substitution.

For this specific question, I want to grab any line that consists entirely of one character in '=' or '-' (smaller subset), with at least 3 of that character, with different conditions about spaces for each.

So I use the following expression to match them:

```
^\t\(=\)\{3,}\_$\|[ ]\{5,}^\(-\)\{3,}\_$
```

What I'd like to do next is to use the submatch in a substitution.  I thought I could just do this:

```
:.s/^\t\(=\)\{3,}\_$\|[ ]\{5,}^\(-\)\{3,}\_$/apple\1banana/e
```

But it only seems to work if the first branch (with the '=') is matched, not the second branch.  How can I make this work?  I'm looking for a solution that would let me use 20 branches and still be able to get the submatch from the matching branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using zero-width patterns and backreferences:

```
\(\%(^\t\)\@<==\{3}\|\%([ ]\{5,}^\)\@<=-\{3}\)\_$
```

A zero-width pattern lets you transform a pattern from matching some characters to matching a position.  `\@<=` just says the preceeding pattern happens just before the current position.

`\zs` is a special case that lets you simplify any pattern that begins with `\%(...\)\@<=` to `...\zs`.

Another approach would simply be to use all the backreferences in the replacement - the ones that come from unmatched branches will be expanded to the empty string:

```
:.s/^\t\(=\)\{3,}\_$\|[ ]\{5,}^\(-\)\{3,}\_$/apple\1\2banana/e
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, you don't need groups. This seems to work the same as your command (I don't have a sample to test):

```
:.s/^\t\zs=\ze=\{2,}$\|^[ ]\{5,}\zs-\ze-\{2,}$/apple&banana/e
```

This will put all the [-=] in the replacement:

```
:.s/^\t\zs=\{3,}$\|^[ ]\{5,}\zs-\{3,}$/apple&banana/e
```

If you could share a sample of the text you need to edit and the expected result it'd make it easier to test if what I write will work or not.

Comment: sorry, yeah, you're totally right, I'll try and put something together. I'm in the midst of writing a plugin for vim and didn't want to make things complicated :P